# Determine if a set of data is from a linear or logarithmic function?

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, data-analysis

I have a set of data points and am curious if the data represents a linear function or a logarithmic function.

The data set is 2 dimensional.

Let's say an ideal set of data points followed the function f(x) = x. If I plotted the data point I would be able to tell it is linear.

Similarly if the data points followed the function f(x) = log(x), I would be able to visually tell it is logarithmic.

On the other hand, having the program determine if a set of data is linear or logarithmic is nontrivial. How would I approach this?

Comment: Linear or log n with respect to what?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviation

Comment: is the data set two dimensional?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? This is a pure algorithm question, not a programming question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'a set of data points' being 'linear or log n' - can you elaborate ?

Comment: are you asking about testing if the data can be modeled linearly (ie satisfies the gauss-markov conditions) or how to compute the relationship assuming it's linear or logarithmic?

Comment: @Bhaskar I'm guessing he's asking if the relationship is logarithmic

Comment: How do you know that it's one or the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option would be to do a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) on the data set to get a best-fit line.  If the data is linear, you'll get a very good fit and the [mean squared error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) should be low.  Otherwise, you'll get an okay fit and a reasonable error.

Alternatively, you could consider transforming the data set by converting each point (x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, y) to (x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>, e<sup>y</sup>).  If the data was linear, now it will be exponential, and if the data was logarithmic, now it will be linear.  Running a linear regression and getting the mean-squared error now will have a low error for the logarithmic data and a staggeringly huge error for the linear data, since the exponential function blows up extremely quickly.

To actually implement the regression, one option would be to use a [least-squares regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).  This would have the added benefit of giving you a correlation coefficient in addition to the model, which could also be used to distinguish between the two data sets.

Because you've asked for how to do this in Java, a quick Google search turned up **[this Java code](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/LinearRegression.java.html)** to do a linear regression.  However, you might have a better fit in a language like Matlab that is specifically optimized to do these sorts of queries.  For example, in Matlab, you can do this regression in one line of code by writing

```
linearFunction = inputs / outputs
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @SeriousTyro- Yes, that's correct.  If the points are truly drawn from a linear function (that is, there's no error at all) the MSE will be zero.

Comment: I LIKE THIS! If I understand it correctly, linear regression gives the best fit line. If it is linear, then the MSE will be low.  Then I could use the MSE for the program to determine if it is linear. Likewise, if I am working with log base 2, I convert each point to 2^x, then data set would be linear and the linear regression will give me a low MSE. Very nice!

Comment: @SeriousTyro- Yeah, that's pretty much it. :-)  Though if you know for a fact that you're dealing with *either* a linear or logarithmic function, then you should exponentiate everything first to magnify the MSE for the linear function.  Glad to help!

Comment: @templatetypedef- There also might be a constant function but that's now a trivial matter. I don't quite understand "exponentiate everything to magnify the MSE." So if I exponentiate my data, the MSE will increase regardless of what type of function it is. Doing this essentially "magnifies" the MSE so it would be easier to threshold the type of function? I am concerned about why one would exponentiate the data instead of simply scaling the MSE.

Comment: @SeriousTyro- If you have data that's linearly distributed, then the MSE of the plot will be small.  If you have data that's logarithmically distributed, then since the function log x grows very slowly, it might appear to be a constant if you just have log values for large numbers.  If you exponentiate everything, then the linear function will be extremely nonlinear (the linear approximation will be terrible), while the log function will have a good fit.  In other words, if you're trying to find which is which, exponentiating will make it easier to spot the log.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. You mentioned that in your original post. That's a pretty elegant way of doing it. =)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not completely correct -- The data could be linear but the MSE could be high, due to noisy data.  A linear regression by itself does not tell you that your data is linear. It *assumes* your data is linear and then gets the line that fits it best, and also measures how well the line fits.

Comment: @DutchMasters- My understanding of the question is that the OP has the actual outputs of a function but doesn't know whether it's linear or logarithmic.  Under this assumption (that is, there is no noise), this answer should work.